# Yii radioButtonList - JUI Buttonset - Hidden input field

Tags: php, jquery-ui, yii

I am new to Yii.

If i generate a radioButtonList using the Yii Form Builder with the following code

```
echo $form->radioButtonList($person,'gender_code',array('m'=>'Male','f'=>'Female'));
```

It outputs the following HTML

```
<input id="ytPerson_gender_code" type="hidden" value="" name="Person[gender_code]" />
<input id="Person_gender_code_0" value="m" type="radio" name="Person[gender_code]" /> 
<label for="Person_gender_code_0">Male</label><br/>
<input id="Person_gender_code_1" value="f" type="radio" name="Person[gender_code]" /> 
<label for="Person_gender_code_1">Female</label>
```

Why is the hidden input field generated? What purpose does it serve.? Is there any way I can remove it?

I am trying to convert the radio buttons into a Jquery UI buttonset but the hidden input field has the same name as the radio buttons and because of that, the jquery UI buttonset breaks.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the yii documentation, it is so that they can still get a value if the radiobutton is unchecked. There should be an htmlOption to tell it not to show. Try:
`radioButtonList($person,'gender_code',array('m'=>'Male','f'=>'Female'),array('uncheckValue'=>NULL))`

Comment: That Worked... I've been trying to find it in the documentation for so long without success.Obviously i didn't look well enough. Thanks a lot.